# Which of these methods provides for the fastest page loading?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I am building a database in MySQL that will be accessed by PHP scripts. I have a table that is the activity stream. This includes everything that goes on on the website (following of many different things, liking, upvoting etc.). From this activity stream I am going to run an algorithm for each user depending on their activity and display relevant activity. Should I create another table that stores the activity for each user once the algorithm has been run on the activity or should I run the algorithm on the activity table every time the user accesses the site?

UPDATE:(this is what is above except rephrased hopefully in an easier to understand way)

I have a database table called `activity`. This table creates a new row every time an action is performed by a user on the website.

Every time a user logs in I am going to run an algorithm on the new rows (since the users last login) in the table (`activity`) that apply to them. For example if the user is following a user who upvoted a post in the activity stream that post will be displayed when the user logs in. I want the ability for the user to be able to access previous content applying to them. Would it be easiest to create another table that saved the rows that have already been run over with the algorithm except attached to individual users names? (a row can apply to multiple different users)

Comment: It might help if you rephrase your question...

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a single table and appropriate indexes. Using a union statement, you can perform several queries (using different indexes) and then mash all the results together.

As an example, lets assume that you are friends with user 37, 42, and 56, and you are interested in basketball and knitting. And, lets assume you have an index on user_id and an index on subject. This query should be quite performant.

```
SELECT * FROM activity WHERE user_id IN (37, 42, 56)
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT * FROM activity WHERE subject IN ("basketball", "knitting")
ORDER BY created
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend tracking your user specific `activities` in a separate table and then upon login you could show all user activities that relate to them more easily.  ie.  So if a user is say big into baseball and hockey you could retrieve that from their recent activity, then got to your everything activities table and grab relevant items from it.